# How to get the result of a getelementptr instruction?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

LLVM IR：`%3 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.demo1, %struct.demo1* %1, i32 0, i32 0`
How do I get the address returned after this instruction is executed?

Comment: The instruction is its result. Instruction inherits Value.

Comment: @arnt Forgive me for asking such a low-level question, but what should I do to get the address after the getelementptr instruction has calculated it?

Comment: `%3` is the address